# Interpolation polynomials with constraints

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, interpolation, applied-mathematics

Lets consider a collection of $n$ points $\{Z_i\}_{i=1}^n\subseteq \mathbb{D}^k(1)=\{(z_1,\ldots,z_k)\in\mathbb{C}^k:\forall j\leq k, |z_j|\leq 1\}$. Let $h: \{Z_i\}_{i=1}^n \to \mathbb{D}^1(1)$ be a sequence of values over $\{Z_i\}_{i\leq n}$, and let  $E:\{Z_i\}_{i\leq n}\to \{\text{complex }k\text{-subspaces of }\mathbb{C}^{k+1}\}$.

Assume that for some small $\epsilon>0$, and for some $\theta\in (0,1)$,

(1) $|h(Z_i)-h(Z_j)|\leq \frac{1}{n^\epsilon}|Z_i-Z_j|$ for all $i,j\leq n$,

(2) $|E(Z_i)-E(Z_j)|\leq |Z_i-Z_j|^\theta$.

I am interested in finding an interpolating polynomial $P:\mathbb{D}^k(\frac{1}{n^\epsilon})\to \mathbb{D}^1(1)$ s.t for $P(Z_i)=h(Z_i)$ for all $i\leq n$.

However I am interested in a little more information on $P$, which has turned out to be hard to find. For starters, I wonder where can I find an interpolation with constraints:
Let $N\in\mathbb{N}$, then I ask that:

(1) $P(Z_i)=h(Z_i)$, $\forall i\leq n$,

(2) $\forall  i\leq n$, $T_{Z_i}P=E(Z_i)$,

(3) $\forall 2\leq r\leq N$, $\forall j\leq k$, $\frac{\partial^r}{\partial z_j^r}P|_{Z_i}=0$, $\forall i\leq n$.

I don’t care much about the degree of the polynomial, as long as I have a concrete reference for its existence. Any references for such a construction? Or Perhaps a clever reduction to the standard case in a higher degree?

Another aspect: For a polynomial over a single variable in $\mathbb{R}$, such an interpolating **piece-wise** polynomial is very easy to construct, as you can simply construct it between any two neighboring points. A solution along those lines is also welcome in my case of a polynomial of a variable in $\mathbb{C}^k$ (if one has an idea of a proper analogue).

Many thanks to all the helpers!

Comment: Do I understand $(2)$ correctly that you just want to specify the first derivatives at $Z_i$?

Comment: @AlekseiKulikov correct, we can think of the case $k=1$, for which the desired polynomial $P$ of degree $3Nn$ is given by the solution for a system of $3Nn$ differential equations. I am ok with that, however I’d like to know that in this case $\|P^{(N)}\|$ is bounded by a constant not depending on $n$. This requires additional information, which I’ll detail in the next comment

Comment: (1) the minimal distance between the points is bigger than $\frac{1}{n^D}$ where $D>1$ (unfortunately) (2) $|h(Z_i)-h(Z_j)|\leq \frac{1}{n^Dn^\epsilon}$.

Comment: Wait, wait, wait, not so fast. The question in your post (about the existence of a polynomial) is a question of algebra, and I can post a construction if you want. However, what you are asking now in the comments, specifically some estimates on said polynomial, is a question of analysis and is significantly deeper, and I can't promise any decent bound on the polynomial.

Comment: The "classical result" that you stated in the second paragraph is incorrect, since when $k=1$ it contradicts the Schwarz-Pick theorem.

Comment: Oh, the OP wants the values of $P$ to lie in $\mathbb{D}^1(1)$, not just in $\mathbb{C}$, I somehow missed it. Then it is indeed not always possible.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I edited the question to be more clear- I had some additional information added in the bottom of the post beforehand, now it’s in the top. I do not see why this is in a contradiction with the Schwarz-Pick lemma? Also, if you are the one who downvoted this question, I’d appreciate if re-upvote it, I would like for it to get exposure as I need some help on this.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Doesn’t the Nevanlina-Pick theorem guarantee the existence of a holomorphic function which satisfies at least the first restriction?